# Volume as double integrals

Tags: geometry, multiple-integral

Find the volume bounded by the cylinder $x^2$+$y^2$=4 and the planes y+z=4 and z=0.

[image]

> My book tells: From the fig, it is self evident that z=4-y is to be integrated over the circle $x^2$+$y^2$=4 in the XY plane. To cover the shaded half of this circle, x varies from 0 to √(4-$y^2$) and y varies from -2 to 2.

And they set the integral :
Volume=$$2\int_{-2}^2\int_0^\sqrt{4-y^2} (4-y)\;dx\;dy$$

Can someone tell me how did they set up this integration. Treat me as a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setp up is as follow

$$2\int_{-2}^2\int_0^\sqrt{4-y^2} (4-y)\;dx\;dy$$

indeed

- we are considering half of the volume starting from the base area of the cylinder
- $y$ varies from $-2$ to $2$
- $x$ varies form $0$ to $\sqrt{4-y^2}$
- the height above is $z=4-y$

Comment: How did u decide limits of x and y and which region are we integrating

Comment: @Abhinav We are integrating over the $(x,y)$ plane by slicing the volume with vertical planes with y=const. For symmetry we can calculate over one half and take twice the result. Therefore, fixed $y$ between $-2$ and $2$ we can determine the variation for $x$ that is between $0$ and $\sqrt{4-y^2}$. For any slice the height is equal to $z=4-y$.

Comment: @Abhinav Note that we can also write $$2\int_{-2}^2 (4-y) dy\int_0^\sqrt{4-y^2} dx=2\int_{-2}^2 (4-y)\sqrt{4-y^2} dy$$

Comment: So what we are doing is : the intersection of cylinder and plane y+z=4 and z=0 is x-y axis?

Comment: And we are integrating over x and y limits here

Comment: @Abhinav Yes of course! We are calculating the volume in between.

Comment: @Abhinav Yes we are considering slices for y=const.

Comment: To be precise, the intersection is the circle, right?

Comment: @Abhinav It is the volume inside the cylinder and between the planes $z=0$ and $z=4-y$.

Comment: @Abhinav We are dividing the volume in slices for y=const. These slices are rectangle with base area $\sqrt{4-y^2}dy$ and height $(4-y)$.

Comment: Yep I got it  . Your explanation is very clear

Comment: @Abhinav That's nice! Well done. Bye